# SeletedIndexChange event of GridView is not firing in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The following code is not executing!!

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow r = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        TxtName.Text = r.Cells[0].Text;
        TextBox2.Text = r.Cells[1].Text;
        TextBox3.Text = r.Cells[2].Text;
        TextBox4.Text = r.Cells[3].Text;
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO! kindly put the html of gridview.

Comment: Hey I got answer .... we need to make the select button enable then only the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged is fired i.e        AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" –

Comment: kindly put it in the answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You must use `EnableViewState="true"`  and bind just one time with `! IsPostBack` in order to not erase your event foreach post.

because when your re build your grid you erase all events

In your page load :

```
if(! IsPostback)
{
   //Bind your Gridview
}
```

Persist your datas with `EnableViewState="true"`

```
 <asp:gridview id="YourGridView"  EnableViewState="true" ...../>
```

Comment: yes i am binding data in !ispostback    if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Bind();
            }

Comment: Hey I got answer ....  we need to make the select button enable then only the  GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged  is fired   i.e   AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"

Answer (score 0):

we need to make the select button enable then only the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged is fired i.e AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"